# How to draw rectangles on image using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to draw 8*8 pixel rectangle on image.
So end output is image with grid of 8*8 pixel windows.

I want to see how rectangles are drawn on image.
i.e. I want to see 1st rectangle drawn then 2nd then 3rd etc.
How to achieve this using Matlab?

Comment: There are **3** *I want* and your question, but not even **1** *I have  tried*

Comment: OOPs I already try to solve it but not get what i actually want and this is my 1st question here and i omit "want" in my next questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for drawing everything in the same plot:

```
hold on
imshow(your_im)
```

plot squares

```
plot([1 1],[1 8],'g')
plot([1 8],[8 8],'g')
plot([8 8],[8 1],'g')
plot([8 1],[1 1],'g')
```

pause the program for `sec` amount of seconds

```
pause(sec);
```

continue drawing another square

```
plot([4 4],[4 12],'r')
plot([4 12],[12 12],'r')
plot([12 12],[12 4],'r')
plot([12 4],[4 4],'r')
```

.
.
.

```
hold off
```

If you want to pause the drawing process until the user press enter use `pause()` instead